# How correctly display color columns for days of week in chart

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I want to show each day of week in diferent color(Monday red, Tuesday green, etc.) and I have problem to correctly display data in chart.
I have series for each day. But with **ChartType:column** the graph is showing each day very ugly(see image here: http://i49.tinypic.com/oszeqt.png ).
data in chart:

```
01:12000
02:12500
03:13000
04:13500
05:14029
06:14509
07:15000
08:15500
09:16000
10:16500
11:17000
12:17125
```

bit of code

```
                        DateTime dateValue = new DateTime(2012, 5, int.Parse(tempDay));

                    switch ((int)dateValue.DayOfWeek)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            chart1.Series["Monday"].Points.AddXY(int.Parse(tempDay), int.Parse(tempTime));
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            chart1.Series["Tuesday"].Points.AddXY(int.Parse(tempDay), int.Parse(tempTime));
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            chart1.Series["Wednesday"].Points.AddXY(int.Parse(tempDay), int.Parse(tempTime));
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            chart1.Series["Thursday"].Points.AddXY(int.Parse(tempDay), int.Parse(tempTime));
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            chart1.Series["Friday"].Points.AddXY(int.Parse(tempDay), int.Parse(tempTime));
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            chart1.Series["Saturday"].Points.AddXY(int.Parse(tempDay), int.Parse(tempTime));
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            chart1.Series["Sunday"].Points.AddXY(int.Parse(tempDay), int.Parse(tempTime));
                            break;
                    }
```

My question:how correctly display each column with color of day. (I don't need separate series for each day.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,i finally found solution!

```
chart1.Series[0]["DrawSideBySide"] = "false";
```

after that you must set width of columns if they are too fat

```
chart1.Series[0]["PointWidth"] = "0.1";
```

this is also can be found in design in series properties in custom properties

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if the colors themselves are your worry, if so, I used something like this:

```
Dim ListOfColors As List(Of String) = Utilities.BuildCustomColorPalette(firstColor)
```

..

```
Public Shared Function BuildCustomColorPalette(colorIN As String) As List(Of String)
      Dim arrCol() As String = {"DarkOrange", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow", "Purple", "Red", "Aqua", "Fuchsia", "Lime", "DodgerBlue", "Gold"}
      Dim listOfColors As New List(Of String)
      listOfColors.Add(colorIN)
      For idx = 0 To arrCol.Length - 1
         If listOfColors.Contains(arrCol(idx)) Then
            'nada
         Else
            listOfColors.Add(arrCol(idx))
         End If
         If listOfColors.Count = 10 Then
            Return listOfColors
         End If
      Next
      Return listOfColors
   End Function
```

..
used like this:

```
Chart.Series(Idx).Color = Color.FromName(ListOfColors(Idx))
```

Comment: for color I simply use chart1.Series["Monday"].Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#C2E5EB"); colors arent my problem